# quero ler mais de 1 arquivo .txt em C

Tags: c, loop

Eu queria criar varios arquivos .txt e fiz isso através de um loop, e consegui. Mas agr o unico jeito que consego ler todos os arquivos é fazendo outro loop, exemplo:  faz um looping de 3 senhas, ou seja, eu criei 3 senhas, 3 arquivos .txt, mas na hora de fazer login eu n quero ter que colocar as 3 senhas, quero que meu programa leia os arquivos e verifique se a unica senha que colocar no login bata com umas das senha ja salva pelo loop.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Paulo. Por favor, poste um trecho do código que você já tem para termos uma ideia melhor do problema, sugiro que leia esse artigo da ajuda do site: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). E, corrije as tags, remove a tag `c++`, se o programa for em `c` mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Em C, o tipo usado para se comunicar através com arquivos é o FILE * como você deve muito bem saber, FILE * é um ponteiro para uma struct que contém dados de um certo arquivo, dados estes *negociados* entre o seu programa e o sistema operacional; em outras palavras, FILE * aponta para um arquivo da mesma forma que void * aponta para uma região de memória. Vários ponteiros podem apontar para uma região de memória, mas um ponteiro não pode apontar para várias regiões de memórias (usa-se vetor de ponteiros - ou ponteiro de segunda ordem - neste caso).

A solução para a sua dúvida seria manipular um arquivo por vez, como você fará isso pode ser de diversas formas, mas a forma mais inteligente seria um vetor de arquivos.

Comment: eu entendi mais ou menos oq vc disse, se eu colocar aqui os codigos vc tenta esclarecer por favor

Comment: Sim Paulo, coloque os códigos que ajudarei o que for possível.

Answer (score 0):

Nesse exemplo, existe uma função que cria na pasta do projeto, arquivos de acordo com a quantidade passada, seguindo o padrão de `arquivo-00`, `arquivo-01` e assim em diante. Para cada arquivo criado, é criada uma senha aleatória, no padrão `ABCDEFG12300`, `ABCDEFG12301` e assim em diante.

Depois de criar os arquivos, é chamada uma função de autenticação, onde é necessário passar uma senha como parâmetro. Ao passar a senha, o programa lê em um `loop`, os arquivos criados, retira a senha contida neles e faz a comparação, caso a senha existir em um dos arquivos, ele mostra a senha e o arquivo que contém a mesma.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int contArq = 0;

void criarArquivos(int numArq) {
    char senha[20];
    strcpy(senha, "ABCDEFG123");

    for (int i = 0; i < numArq; i++) {
        FILE *arquivo;
        char nomeArq[100];

        sprintf(nomeArq, "arquivo-%02d.txt", i);

        sprintf(senha, "ABCDEFG123%02d", i);

        arquivo = fopen(nomeArq, "w");

        fputs(senha, arquivo);

        if (arquivo != NULL) {
            fclose(arquivo);

            contArq++;
        } else {
            perror(nomeArq);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

void autenticarSenha(char senha[]) {
    char linha[100];
    char nomeArq[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < contArq; i++) {
        FILE *arquivo;
        sprintf(nomeArq, "arquivo-%02d.txt", i);

        arquivo = fopen(nomeArq, "r");

        while(fgets(linha, sizeof linha, arquivo) != NULL){
            if(strcmp(linha, senha) == 0){
                printf("Autenticacao concluida, a senha se encontra no arquivo %s", nomeArq);
                printf("\nSenha: %s", linha);

            }
        }

        fclose(arquivo);
    }
}

main(){
    char senha[100];
    strcpy(senha, "ABCDEFG12303");

    criarArquivos(5);

    autenticarSenha(senha);
}
```